# is it possible for scala superclass return this as subclass

Tags: scala

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  def method() = this
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
  def method1() = this
}
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
  def method2() = this
}

val obj1 = new SubClass1()
obj1.method1().method() // this is ok
val obj2 = new SubClass2()
obj2.method().method2() // this is not ok, as method returns a SuperClass, 
                        // which has no method named method2
```

So how to make the `method` return the subclass type so I can chain the operation in any order.

So far what I can think is to follow something like

```
abstract class SuperClass[T <: SuperClass[T]]
```

but I don't know how to continue that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  def method(): this.type = this
}
```

Comment: it works, would you please also tell how to achieve this in java?

Comment: There is no equivalent in java. You'd have to override `method` in each subclass

Answer (score 3):

I find the following approach works as well:

```
abstract class SuperClass[T <: SuperClass[T]] {
  def method(): T = this.asInstanceOf[T]
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass[SubClass] {
  def method1() = this
}

val obj = new SubClass()
obj.method1().method()
obj.method().method1()
```

Comment: It kinda depends on what exactly you mean by "works" :) This breaks badly at runtime with something like `class Foo extends SuperClass[SubClass]` or with just `new SuperClass[SubClass]().method`

Comment: @Dima it should be `class Foo extends SuperClass[Foo]`, the second case must not work as `SuperClass` is `abstract`.